# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in web-scraping

Tags: web-scraping, attributeerror

I'm trying to recreate the web scraping on this website

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe

I'm working in jupyter as a first project and I've come up with this error

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

I've tried changing the link but it makes no difference.  I don't really know enough to do anything about the problem.  Here is all the code so far...

```
#import the libraries
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# specify the url
quote_page = "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/SP1:IND"
page = urllib.request.urlopen(quote_page)
# parse the html using BeautifulSoup and store in variable `soup`
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
# Take out the <div> of name and get its value
name_box = soup.find("h1", attrs={"class": "name"})
name = name_box.text.strip() 
# strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
print (name)
# get the index price
price_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price"})
price = price_box.text.strip()
print (price)
```

Any help would be appreciated a lot

Answer (score 0):

I use selenium to webscrape, but I am sure I can help you out (maybe).
This section is were you code gives you the error I assume:

```
price_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price"})
price = price_box.text.strip()
print (price)
```

What I would do is:

```
price_box = soup.find("div", attrs={"class":"price"})
price = price_box().text
print (price.text)
```