# I am getting error like AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.adityaispat.com/vision-mission.html', verify=False)

#url = "https://www.aarti-industries.com/csr/"

#page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find(class_="text").text) 

or

print(soup.find('td', attrs={'class': 'text'}).text)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' in web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52667551/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-text-in-web-scraping)

Comment: No, still getting same error@NicolasGervais

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to your question is that `find()` method returns object of type `NoneType` and you're trying to read `text` from it. To prevent this, it's worth to check first if `find()` gives any result.

```
result = soup.find(class_="text")
if result:
    print(result.text)
else
    # other action
```

Another answer is question: what you're trying to find? Maybe your class and/or atrributes to search are defined incorrectly.

I in your case the true source of problem is `request` part. If you check `page.status_code`, you'll notice that it returns 406, that means request was unseccessful.
Basing on this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101612/python-requests-http-response-406) you need to use a different User-Agent. Also remember to check if request was successful. Siplme way is to use `ok` property.

```
page = requests.get('https://www.adityaispat.com/vision-mission.html', headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
if page.ok:
    print('Request OK!')
    # process the page
else:
    print('Request Failed!')
```

Comment: No didn't get any output and you can check the URL, I want all the text data which have class = text in the URL.

Comment: I investigate your issue and extended answer. Now it should be ok. Good advice - try to write robust code, to avoid situation like this - think "What if? What else?" You've got two isses like that in your code.